Obtener ID en la misma transacción (antes de hacer commit). JAVA/JPA
CONTEXTO
En la página web que estoy haciendo tengo 2 tablas. 1 para Pedidos y la otra es una relación entre el producto y los pedidos (Algo así como SubPedidos). Las tecnologías que estoy usando son Java con JPA y MaríaDB.

Aquí las tablas:
CREATE TABLE pedido (
   id  BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   idUsuario BIGINT NOT NULL,
   fecha TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   precioTotal DOUBLE NOT NULL,
   terminado BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   idStripe VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   
   
   FOREIGN KEY (idUsuario) REFERENCES usuario (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);


/*
*********************************
         SUBPEDIDOS
*********************************
*/
CREATE TABLE pedido_productoOcurrencia (
   idPedido  BIGINT NOT NULL,
   idOcurrencia BIGINT  NOT NULL,
   cantidadProducto INT NOT NULL,
   subTotal DOUBLE NOT NULL,
   
   PRIMARY KEY(idPedido, idOcurrencia),
   FOREIGN KEY (idPedido) REFERENCES pedido (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (idOcurrencia) REFERENCES productoOcurrencia (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);


La cuestión. A la hora de insertar los pedidos quiero insertar también los subpedidos dentro de la misma transacción, porque de nada sirve tener un pedido si no tengo también qué productos hay en el pedido.
PROBLEMA
Mi problema es que a la hora de insertarlo todo junto en la misma transacción, necesito el id del pedido para establecerlo en los subpedidos. ¿Qué pasa? Que según estoy viendo si el id es autoincremental este no se genera hasta realizar el commit, por lo que no tengo forma de adjuntarlo a los subpedidos dentro de la misma transacción.
No tengo este problema si utilizo el id de Stripe (Stripe es una api de Pagos) como clave principal porque me lo genera él, permitiéndome así establecer el id con anterioridad, sin embargo, preferiría utilizar un numérico porque los id de Stripe son algo largos. Teniendo en cuenta que por cada pedido se insertan muchos subpedidos, no resulta muy eficiente que digamos.
El código en el DAO sería una cosa así:
 /**
     *
     * @param pedido
     * @param carrito
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public String insert(Pedido pedido, CarroProductos carrito) throws SQLException {
        EntityManager eManager = GestorEntityManager.getEntityManager();
        eManager.getTransaction().begin();

        // ***********************
        //Se insertan el pedido y los subPedidos.
        //Si ocurre algun problema se borra todo.
        eManager.persist(pedido);
           ArrayList<SubPedido> listaSubPedidos = crearSubPedidos(pedido.getId(), carrito);
            for (SubPedido subPedido : listaSubPedidos) {
            eManager.persist(subPedido);
          }
        // ***********************
        eManager.getTransaction().commit();
        eManager.close();
        return pedido.getId();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param idPedido
     * @param carrito
     * @return
     */
    private ArrayList<SubPedido> crearSubPedidos(String idPedido, CarroProductos carrito) {
        ArrayList<SubPedido> listaSubPedidos = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ProductoOcurrencia ocurrencia : carrito.getProductos()) {
            SubPedido subPedido = new SubPedido();

            SubPedidoPK subPedidoPK = new SubPedidoPK();
            subPedidoPK.setIdOcurrencia(ocurrencia.getId());
            subPedidoPK.setIdPedido(idPedido);

            subPedido.setSubPedidoPk(subPedidoPK);
            subPedido.setCantidadProducto(ocurrencia.getCantidad());
            subPedido.setSubTotal(ocurrencia.getCantidad() * ocurrencia.getPrecioUnidad());
            listaSubPedidos.add(subPedido);
        }
        return listaSubPedidos;
    }

PREGUNTA
Por tanto mi pregunta estaría en si existe alguna forma de obtener el número (del id generado) en la misma transacción o si existe alguna alternativa más eficiente que utilizar el id de Stripe.
Anotación: El código de programación que he puesto es de la implementación "siendo el id el de Stripe", por eso en el parámetro del método "crearSubPedidos" es "String idPedido" en vez de "Long idPedido".

Podrías plantear un campo a mayores uuid, generando lo antes de la transacción, y que uses en tus join ese uuid en lugar del id autonumerico. Así ya sabes de antemano el id para todo (porque lo autogeneras)

Hola, como te comentaron, tal vez sea mejor cambiar de estrategia y utilizar uuids como ids de tu tabla generándolos en el lado del cliente. Hay varias implementaciones de uuid, pero me parece buena práctica implementar uuid versión 6 que tiene la ventaja de ser ordenado (las claves se generan en orden alfabético) y esto se lleva mejor con las estructuras de tipo arbol b que utilizan las bases de datos. Hay ejemplos de cómo implentar la versión 6 usando como base la versión 1. El único problema sería que tendrías que cambiar el tipo de tu id a String y tal vez no quieras hacer un cambio así.

Consulta normal

No estoy seguro, pero creo que funciona. En su getting started está el ejemplo
@Entity
class Material{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  // Getters y Setters
}

interface MaterialRepository extends Repository<Material, Long> {

  Person save(Material material);

  Optional<Material> findById(long id);
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  CommandLineRunner runner(MaterialRepository repository) {
    return args -> {

      Material material = new Material();
      material.setName("Martillo");

      repository.save(person);
      Material saved = repository.findById(material .getId()).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
    };
  }
}

Procedimientos almacenados

Otra forma de lograrlo es mediante procedimientos almacenados
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyDb.createMaterial(
    IN name VARCHAR(64),
    ...
    OUT material_id_out
) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ...
    SET material_id_out = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END //
DELIMITER ;

@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Material.register", procedureName = "createMaterial", parameters = {
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "name", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "material_id_out", type = Integer.class) })
public class Material{}

